# Paste content without markup in Gmail on Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, copy-paste

When I paste content in Gmail (on Chrome on the Mac) it copies markup. Using Shift-CMD-V doesn't do anything. Right-clicking doesn't work either. For short texts I can paste it in the subject line, then copy it there, then paste it into the content, which is a shitty solution.

Why doesn't this work normally? I thought Shift-paste was a generally used solution to this problem.

Comment: Content coming from where? And what kind of markup?

Comment: Content from a website, viewed in Chrome, so HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the correct shortcut for Chrome on osX is

```
Command-Shift-Option-V
```

Answer (score 1):

[@sigmud answer's](https://superuser.com/a/1364892/146254) is my preferred way, but you can also use Gmail's "Remove Formatting"

[image: remove formatting screenshot]